# Center a div vertically/horizontally resizing it at the same time

Tags: css, css-position

As the question says, I am trying to center a `div` on the middle of the screen both `horizontally/vertically` and resize it at the same time.

I do not have any problems on resizing the `content` when the screen is smaller even to center the `wrapper` when it is displayed on big screens, the problems comes when I try to resize the screen and, as the `wrapper` has a `max-height` property, it does not never vertically center when resize the screen (because it occupy `300px` all the time).

I would like that the `div` that is centered (`wrapper`) never will be more than `300px` and will be always centered (both `vertically/horizontally`).

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="content">
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html{
   width: 100%;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Error404Stack/9qaanfjk/).

I tried a lot of configurations and looked a lot of questions here on StackOverflow but any of them worked for me because most of them are only for  `horizontally/vertically` center or resize a `div`, but not both.

**Note:** I cannot use `flexbox` and I would like to maintain as much as possible the actual `CSS` code, if possible.

How can I avoid to use `max-height` (that is broken my `vertically` centering) and get the same behaviour?

---

**EDIT:** The `div` is already centered both `vertically/horizontally`. **What I want is that the square will be always a square and always be centered**. I am sorry if I do not put it very clear.

Now the content is being resize as I want (as a square), the problem is only with vertically align at the same time it resizes.

---

**EDIT 2:** If you want to see the effect that I refer in the above edit, resize the screen on my example JSFiddle horizontally and you will see the effect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MatthewJohnson I already have the wrapper centered both `horizontally/vertically`. I had already see the question that you put as related. The problem is that any of the cases worked very well for me (when I try to maintain the square as a square all the time at the same time it is being centered).

Comment: Oops!  Missed that part, comment deleted.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson It seems that you are not the only one person who missunderstood the question. I am sorry for that. It is the reason why I added two more edits to clarify it. Thanks for delete your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this with CSS3 `transform`. It depends of the browsers support you want to offer.

I would suggest to place your content `absolute` at 50% of your wrapper. Then, you can use a negative translate of 50%. `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` will place your content top left corner in the middle. Negative translate of 50% (`translate(-50%, -50%)`) will move your content half of its width to the left and half of its height to the top.

```
#content{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You can see your updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qaanfjk/1/)

---

EDIT

I misunderstood a part of your question the first time. But you can easily merge a part of your solution and mine to get what you want.

You just need to replace `height: 100%;` with `padding-bottom: 100%;` of my previous answer above:

```
#content{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

See this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qaanfjk/2/).

Comment: But in your case the div is not resizing as in my case. It always have to be a square and be centered.

Comment: @Error404 I just edited my answer. I think this is more closer now of what you want. Please let me know!

Comment: The second answer works fine for me. Nice to see translate being used!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! But I have some doubts: **1.** I do not know what you mean when you say _You just need to replace height: 100% with padding-bottom: 100%_ because I already had `padding-bottom` property. **2.** Can you explain a bit more explained why you set top 50% and left 50% and then use translate?. **3.** If you see, the wrapper is still 300px when you resize it so I think it can make problems in a real project with a lot of elements on the webpage. Could it be posible to adapts the wrapper to the content? Thanks again!

Comment: @Error404
1. The replacement of `height: 100%` by `padding-bottom: 100%` is from my previous answer.
2. `top` and `left` at 50% will place your content top left corner in the middle. Negative `translate` of 50% will move your content half of its width to the left and half of its height to the top.
3. The wrapper is made to center yhis element while keeping its max size. You will probably need a second wrapper for your other elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something(?), but it looks like you can just add `height:100%;` to your `#content` css instead of `padding-bottom` and it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/puajxgsz/

Also, I played with another way to do it without absolutely positioning anything...because, well, it was sort of interesting:

https://jsfiddle.net/j0ch7oxj/

Comment: No, but what I am looking is that the square maintains the aspect ratio (to be always a square) also. I am sorry if I do not let it very clear on the question.

Comment: And I use `padding-bottom: 100%` to have the same `height` taking as reference the `width`.